# How can I see a discussion with both sides in Twitter?

Tags: twitter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tracking conversations in twitter](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/6605/tracking-conversations-in-twitter)

When I open somebody's tweets page, I often see his responses to his friends' posts, but without those posts themselves. Is there a way to see someone's tweets and all replies to them in one feed?

Comment: Strange how Twitter doesn't give the original tweet for @replies off your follow list :-/

Comment: Try this http://tweetree.com/

Comment: Look at http://www.tweetconvo.com/

Answer (score 4):

The latest update to the Twitter.com web UI has this ability as well.

Comment: Twitter has been rolling out the new version for the past two weeks, so if you don't have it yet when you go to twitter.com, it's coming.

Comment: I already have new UI. I've just opened a twitter of a friend of mine, I see his responses, but I don't see posts he's responding to.

Comment: Oh I think you need to be following both people in the conversation, not just your friend to see both sides in the Twitter UI

Answer (score 0):

[The Cadmus](http://www.thecadmus.com/) can do this for you:

> **The Power of Conversations.**
>
> Cadmus takes the @replies in your Twitter stream and groups them into conversations. So the next time your friends are talking about the latest news, you won't feel like you are missing out. Read more about it [here](http://blog.anomalyinnovations.com/2010/02/twitter-conversations-in-cadmus/).

Comment: Does it work if I'm not following one of the sides?

Comment: No, you will need to at least add them to a list I think... A private list is seen by nobody except yourself and can be used for this purpose. For a more on-the-fly method I guess you will need to look for an alternative...

Answer (score 0):

You can see the whole conversation via the web site. Old or new version. Click the tweet in question and then click the button "in reply to"

That will show all the tweets that either person has replied to on one view.